# LSTMs with multi-dimensional output targets

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

Given a time series of 3D vectors, `[x, y, z]` where x, y, and z are arbitrary integers, I'd like to build a model that predicts the next vector in the series and captures patterns in each of the dimensions x, y, z.

So if `X = [[0, 0, 6], [1, 0, 0], [9, 9, 9], [3, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3]]` and I give my model the 4-element sequence `[[0, 0, 6], [1, 0, 0], [9, 9, 9], [3, 0, 3]]` it would predict `[1, 2, 3]`

I can't just one-hot encode each vector since the numbers can have arbitrary values, so I'm wondering how I can accomplish this. Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried implementing a model that consists of one or multiple LSTM layer(s) followed by a dense layer? Just run `model.predict(test_data)` then `round` the results and see if it is close to true values. I am not sure it would be accurate, I am just asking whether you have tried this approach on your data or not.

Comment: I have, but I had trouble interpreting the prediction vector I was getting, so I figured I might be missing something fundamental. Here is a question I posted toward the end of that process (which includes my model) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014044/keras-lstm-multidimensional-output-error-expected-time-distributed-17-to-have

Comment: In your solution, removing `TimeDistributed` and adding a dense layer of size three, what activation function you use for the last layer? Actually there shouldn't be any activation function because you are doing (vector) regression.

Comment: I use softmax. It's in the model at the bottom unless you mean a different layer? And I don't think regression works here because the z value in my vectors corresponds to a one-hot-encoded letter so there won't be a pattern that regression can find, I don't think. Am I wrong?

Comment: Am I missing something? Aren't you interested in predicting a vector `[x,y,z]` where `x`, `y` and `z` are arbitrary integers (and are not bounded, so they can't be encoded or discretized)?

Comment: Yes, that's right—maybe I misunderstood. Were you saying that a regression would be a better choice for this task over LSTMs? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173773/discussion-between-paul-and-today).

Comment: If you are predicting real values or unbounded integer values then It is a regression task. Regression is the category of the problem not a layer. So you could have LSTM layers in a network for solving a regression task.

Comment: Could you point me to an example of this kind of network—a tutorial or github repo?

Comment: Well, there is a series of Jupyter notebooks written by the creator of Keras (actually those are selected chapters of a book he has written). Specifically, [this one](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/3.7-predicting-house-prices.ipynb) discusses regression. In your case, since you are working with timeseries data you may need to use one or more LSTM layers in your model as well, which you can read more about [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.2-understanding-recurrent-neural-networks.ipynb) and >>>>>>

Comment: >>>>> [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.ipynb). Let me know if you could not work it out after reading these and I will try to write a simple model, as an starting point, to address the problem you are working on.

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I'll see this gives me enough to move forward.

Comment: Ok, I read through those examples as well as David's response below and I realized that I had put off rescaling my vector elements. Once I normalized them to values between 0 and 1 and re-ran my model, things started to make more sense. I'm now topping out at 0.5 accuracy and don't know why, but that's better than instantly hitting 1.0 on the second epoch.

Comment: @today here's my latest question about this model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145007/3-vector-series-lstm-cant-break-0-5-accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input, in this case, is just the vector. At timestep 1 the vector is `[0,0,6]`, at timestep 2 the vector is `[1,0,0]`, and so on. For the output you are expected to pass the output through a fully connected layer that transforms it to the correct size for output.

Assuming your sequence length is fixed you really don't have any preprocessing to do here, except perhaps standardizing or rescaling your inputs so they aren't very large numbers.

In general, an RNN works a lot like a fully connected network. In fact an RNN cell is made up of 4 fully connected networks that are simply piped together in a non-trivial way. But from the perspective of what you put in and what you get out, think of them like a simple fully connected network (per each timestep).

You can read up more on my last paragraph here: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

If your sequence length is variable then you would typically add an input that flags it as the prediction step. This could simply be all zero's such as:

```
X = [[0, 0, 6], [1, 0, 0], [9, 9, 9], [3, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0]]
```

or, if `[0,0,0]` is a valid datapoint you could add a feature to flag the timestep as an input or a prediction such as:

```
X = [[0, 0, 0, 6], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 9, 9, 9], [0, 3, 0, 3], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Where the first value in that dataset indicates if the timestep is an input `0` or a prediction `1`.

You will have outputs at each timestep which you will ignore. Your loss function will be based only on the output of the last timestep.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, David. I've already put an LSTM model together but had trouble interpreting the output, so I think I'm missing something else in my understanding. Here is another question I posed which includes my model and my confusion about the output (in the UPDATE): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014044/keras-lstm-multidimensional-output-error-expected-time-distributed-17-to-have